# Meaning of "beat down"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

> Although Apple and Google have said that their contact-tracing apps would limit applications that tried to create a centralised database of contacts, the government has **beaten down** Apple on its security principles before.

What does beat down mean in the above passage?

Comment: For a non-racist view of the idiom, consider a kid on a playground, surrounded by a bunch of bullies punching and kicking him.

Answer (score 1):

'Beat down' is often claimed to be a multi-word verb (many use the term 'phrasal verb'), and there are many senses. Perhaps the most common transitive usage is the metaphorical sense 'get someone to reduce a price [substantially] by hard bargaining'.

..............

But the [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+down) probably best gives the sense here:

> 3. To strike something so violently as to cause its collapse [/capitulation]. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between
>      "beat" and "down."

So a metaphorical 'beaten into submission'.

*The Government has ruled powerfully against such proposed measures.*

(I've had to read the related linked article behind the one you quote from, and 'forced the companies to ensure greater privacy safeguards', ie 'got a better 'bargain' for the end-user', might well apply. But a tussle is still involved.)

Comment: I would not be surprised if the "beaten into submission" meaning gained foothold during the slavery era, alluding to a slave owner wielding a whip against one of his slaves.